# Conditionally selecting sublists from a large JSON generated list

Tags: r

I have a list generated from an API pull and converted from JSON by the `httr` package.

It has 80-odd top level numbered elements / lists, each of which contains between 10 next-level elements / lists. At this next level I'd like to be able to filter so I only have the 1 from the 10 that has the name "My Color" , I don't want the other 9 that don't match.

Here is the output in R for the 2nd level, (1 of 10) list:

```
..$ data:List of 10
  .. ..$ :List of 3
  .. .. ..$ id       : int 1
  .. .. ..$ name     : chr "My Color"
  .. .. ..$ color:List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ data:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :List of 3
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ id  : int 15
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ name: chr "Blue"
```

I'm struggling to get a reproducible data example due to the complexity of the list, but the end goal would be to preserve the 80 top level elements, but with each containing the 1 sublist whose 'name' element contains 'My Color'.

Again apologies for the lack of a reproducible example, but a pointer to the correct approach would be appreciated. I'm really struggling with manipulating lists.

Comment: See `?purrr::keep` or `?Filter`

Comment: Can you share the API, or `dput` an example response?

Comment: Hi @Brian it's a commercial API, I changed the names above for representation, so I'm struggling with a reproducible example that doesn't violate terms.

Comment: Without seeing an example structure that's not truncated, my best guess would be `library(tidyverse); flatten(flatten(keep(.x$name == "My Color"))`